# How to pass hex values to a python script from command line

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I have a simple script that passes a command (hex value) to a uC using I2C. I wanted to pass the address and command values through the command line as argv's.

Here is my code:

```
import smbus
import time
from sys import argv

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
addr = argv[1]
cmd = argv[2]

#address is 0x09
#commands = [0x16,0x06,0x17,0x07,0x18,0x08,0x19,0x09]

bus.write_byte(addr,cmd)
```

I've tried to write

```
python progam.py 0x09 0x19
python program.py 9 25
```

And have also tried to convert the argv's into int() then to hex. None of these things has worked.

How can I pass hex values into my program?

Comment: are you looking for `int(value, 16)`?

Comment: @ritlew im guessing that wont work with the 0x bit...

Comment: they are passing in as strings right? and you want to get the actual value?

Comment: it works as the answer below. Just converting to int() is all that I needed. The uC accepts that and doesn't need it to be hex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import smbus
import time
from sys import argv

bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
if sys.argv[1].startswith("0x"): # base 16
    addr = int(argv[1][2:],16)
    cmd = int(argv[2][2:],16)
else: # base 10
    addr = int(argv[1])
    cmd = int(argv[2])
print [addr,cmd] # you should see no quotes indicating that these are indeed ints now                          
bus.write_byte(addr,cmd)
```

then call it with `$ python my_script.py 9 25`
or call it with `$ python my_script.py 0x09 0x19`

Comment: You might want to add the base as 16

Comment: perhaps just an if statement to see if argv[i][0:2] == '0x'?

Comment: The int(value, 16) works with the '0x' prefix. At least in 2.7 it does. `int('0x19', 16) >>> 25`

Comment: calling `int(argv[1],16)` and `int(argv[2], 16)` would work fine.

Comment: hmmm I thought it wouldnt work ... my bad ... oh well it certainly does not need it so my solution should still be fine

Comment: @JoranBeasley I tried the int(argv[1],16) method, it works as well, but the difference is that I enter the arguments as hex, without the '0x'. So for 25, I enter 19.